# Problemas con DateTime e Int al hacer un SELECT en C#

Tags: c#, sql, .net

Tengo el siguiente modelo en C#:

```
`namespace PC
{
    public class Computer
    {

        public string Motherboard { get; set; }

        public int Cores { get; set; }

        public bool HasWifi { get; set; }

        public bool HasLTE { get; set; }

        public DateTime ReleaseTime { get; set; }

        public decimal Price { get; set; }

        public string VideoCard { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`

Hice mi conexión a mi base de datos de esta forma: `IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);`

Hago esta query utilizando Dapper: `IEnumerable<Computer> result_select = connection.Query<Computer>(select_query);`

Y finalmente hago este ciclo para ver los resultados en consola:

```
foreach (Computer computer in result_select)
{
   

    Console.WriteLine(computer.Cores.ToString(), computer.Price);
    Console.WriteLine($@"DATOS DE LA COMPUTADORA:
                        Nombre: {computer.Motherboard}
                        Nucleos del CPU: {computer.Cores}
                        Tarjeta gráfica: {computer.VideoCard}
                        Wifi: {computer.HasWifi}
                        LTE: {computer.HasLTE}
                        Precio: {computer.Price}
                        Consulta realizada el: {computer.ReleaseTime}");
}
```

Y me imprime lo siguiente:

[image: Salida en la consola]

Todo bien, excepto porque hay dos problemas:
[image: Tabla de la base de datos]

El primero es que, en ambas ocasiones (tengo dos filas insertadas, pero en ambas ocurre el mismo problema), en el campo de Cores, debería de devolverme los respectivos números insertados en esos campos de la base de datos (12 y 16 respectivamente) pero en ambas, el valor de `computer.Cores` es 0 en C#

El segundo, es que, también, en ambas filas, en vez de devolverme la fecha correcta que esta insertada en la base de datos, me devuelve `01/01/0001 0:00:00`

Comment: Yo de Dapper ni idea, pero así como pintas el problema pareciera que los nombres de las propiedades deben coincidir con los nombres de las columnas

Comment: Sí, muchas gracias, efectivamente era eso